# Reading text file using JavaScript and updating the value in the browser in real time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a JavaScript file which reads the value of a text file and gives it to the main HTML page for the clients to view.

HTML code

```
 <div class="column" >

       <div class ="header2">
         <h1> </h1>                // fill whatever is coming from the js file
        </div>

</div>
```

The javascipt function which reads the txt file and stores the data into splitStatus[0] and splitStatus[1] to output in the HTML.

```
var status;
function readTextFile1(file)
{
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
               status = rawFile.responseText;
              
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}
 readTextFile1("newfile.txt");


console.log(status);

let splitStatus=status.split('\n')
for(let i=0;i<splitStatus.length;i++){

  console.log(splitStatus[1]);
  console.log(splitStatus[0]);
}
```

Then in the same javascript file i have this code which gives splitStatus[0] and splitStatus[1] to the HTML file

```
const BOX_1 = document.querySelectorAll('.column');
const chld7= BOX_1[0].querySelector('.header2 > h1');
chld7.innerText = " Status :"+" "+splitStatus[0]+"";
```

All of this is working very well, but the only problem is that the the text only updates when i do a refresh.

Is there a way that the browser can automatically look into that text every 1 second and update the most recent data without me refreshing ?

Comment: do not use synchronous Ajax calls it is a bad practice. GET requests get cached. Call the code on a timeout to keep updating or learn about websockets.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a polling solution, then setInterval() and setTimeout() are your friends.

However, in general, you want to turn the problem the other way around. You want to find an event that is fired every time there is a change to a view. Then you listen for that event and act accordingly. This is non-trivial if the events happen on the serverside; you may want to look into WebSockets.

Comment: do do i need to call the set interval inside my html file so that it will call my JavaScript file every x seconds?